# How do you export a program in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Recently I finished up a couple programs in Visual Studio (2015). I put these programs on a flash drive with the goal of being able to show them off on other computers.

Do I need to keep a copy of Visual Studio on the flash drive in case the computer I'm running it on doesn't have it? And if not how do I get my program to run without the compiler?

Comment: No....You need to build the .exe.  That is all and include any dlls.  Right click next to 'debug' on toolbar and select 'release.'  Then click 'start.'  This will build a release for you program.  Will only work on machines with .net installed though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where do I find, and where do I put the dlls?

Comment: If u export to .exe or something like that, database Will export too?

Answer (score 18):

Here are some basic steps to build your application (more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyz1h6zd.aspx)):

- In solution Explorer right click on your project and click "Build" (point 1. in the screenshot)
- Once the build is complete right click again on your project and click "Open Folder in File Explorer" (point 2. in the screenshot)
- Visual studio will open a Windows Explorer window with a lot of files and folders. Open the "bin" folder
- Inside the bin folder you will find a folder called "Debug" or a folder called "Release" depending on the build configuration you chose. Inside the "Debug" (or "Release") folder you will find all the resources required to run your application (usually a .exe file, a .config file and some DLL files)
- You can copy the content of this folder to your flash drive and your program will run on any computer that has the correct version of the .net framework installed

Here is a Visual Studio 2015 screenshot that shows where to find the commands you need:

[image]

Comment: Database Will convert too?